# problem with google directions api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

A user comes to my web app and locates the destination address but he does not locate the source location and publishes the page. The normal user who are not registered to the web app adds the source location.

Once the user adds the source location he is not able to see the exact direction map, rather the google is displaying the default maps.

Here is the exception giving when we used chrome console.

I have added the code here and also the exception I am getting

```
Error Name:
main.js:41Uncaught TypeError:Object#<object> has no method 'Load'


function calcRoute() {
    showDirections();
  document.getElementById('directionsPanel').innerHTML="";
    initialize();
  var start = document.getElementById("txt_from").value;
  var end = getDestinationAdderss(document.getElementById('final_address').innerHTML);
  var request = {
    origin:start, 
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
```

[image]

```
function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_directions"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
}
```

Comment: The error is happening on line 41 of main.js.  What does the code look like there?  (Or is main.js something in the Google API and not something you wrote?)

Comment: @Trott: Yes the error is in main.js, but I am not able to identify whats wrong with that, it was working fine before, I just changed the UI, now its giving some problem

Comment: What does the code look like on line 41 of main.js? (Or is main.js something in the Google API and not something you wrote?)

Comment: @Troot: i have added the screen shot just have a look and kindly help me

Comment: The code in the screenshot is unreadable. Also it looks minified, and debugging minified code just won't work. If it is something you wrote then please change to a version that is not minified. If it is something in the Google API then at least say so.

Comment: @Arjan @Trott Hello, the error is in main.js:41Uncaught TypeError:Object#<object> has no method 'Load' I have also added the google map api which i used

Comment: Ok, main.js is a Google file, I found it. And it is working properly in the Google samples, so the problem is **not** in main.js. Also it has been working on your site. So the problem has to do with the UI changes you made. Solution is to undo the changes, confirm that it is working again, then again make the desired changes and make _sure_ you do not break any code.

Comment: Please post the initialize() routine.  The call stack in your image screenshot indicates that the error-producing code goes there last before heading off to main.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debug screenshot indicates that initialize() is the last bit of code run in your file before Google Maps API throws the error.  So look in there (and/or provide that code in your question).

**UPDATE**: Based on your code, the first to check might be to make sure that there is an element with an id of `map_canvas_directions` and another one with an id of `directionsPanel`.  There's not enough information to say for sure, but if I had to guess, your UI changes got rid of one or the other of those elements, but your code requires them.

**UPDATE TO THE UPDATE**: Replacing the stuff in the DirectionsRenderer() constructor as @Arjan suggests is also a likely cause of your problem so definitely try that too!

Comment: @Jeevan: Since this is the accepted answer, it should be safe to conclude that your problem has been solved. So I think I don't have to post which code still seems missing.

Comment: @Arjan: sorry the problem is not yet solved actually. kindly help me to solve this problem.I can give more information on this.

Answer (score 3):

You have removed some code that is present in the [Google sample](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-directions/draggable-directions.html).

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    'map': map,
    'preserveViewport': true,
    'draggable': true
});
```

I expect that your code is working again if you add the code above in the proper place. If not, you really should start with the sample code again, since that does work.

Comment: @Trott : hello, I tried the things which u suggested but its not working for me. Can I have u r email ID, if you dont mind